# Picking data from Excel CSV using iMacros

Tags: imacros

I want to automate the submission of deleted pages in Google Search Console for a website that I manage.

That's what I wrote in iMacros for Chrome (I've replaced my-domain.name.com and my-file.csv with the real names, of course):

```
VERSION BUILD=1011 RECORDER=CR
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\MY-USERNAME\Desktop\my-file.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP YES
SET !LOOP 1
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://search.google.com/search-console/removals?resource_id=https://www.my-domain-name.com/&hl=fr&utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=deprecation-pane&utm_content=url-removal
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Nouvelle<SP>demande
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:newremovalform ATTR=NAME:urlt CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Suivante
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Envoyer<SP>la<SP>demande
WAIT SECONDS=15
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/webmasters/tools/removals-submit-ac?hl=fr&siteUrl=https://www.my-domain-name.com/ ATTR=NAME:next
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:the-form ATTR=ID:submit-button
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

But when I play the macro, I immediately get this error message:

> Blockquote SyntaxError: wrong format of SET command at line 2

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,
Eva.

Answer (score 0):

FCI not mentioned (check my Profile on how to ask Qt's about the `iMacros` Tag "a bit correctly"...), but you probably have some Space(s) in the Path for your DataSource, I reckon...

=> Probable FCI:
`iMacros for CR v10.1.1, CR93/94(...?), Win7/10/11(...?).`

=> Need to replace Spaces with `<SP>`...  :idea:
... Or you can enclose the whole Path with Single or Double Quotes... (But the Backslashes then need to be escaped with another Backslash...)

What also would cause "a Problem" is if your Path (including the Filename) contains some Single Quote(s)..., ... that you then can try to escape also, or maybe easier is to make sure that your Path "avoids" Spaces and "Special" Chars...

It's all documented and explained (with Examples) in the Wiki for the [`!DATASOURCE`](https://wiki.imacros.net/!DATASOURCE#Examples) Command...